# micro web-framework for c

Tags: c

For a weekend project I'm looking for a micro web-framework like bottle.py (http://bottlepy.org) but for plain old C. Sadly Google was not very helpful. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Google sez: [Raphters](http://thechangelog.com/post/4608227295/raphters-a-web-framework-for-c)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Looks promising - although the documentation is nearly inexistent.

Comment: Raphters is incomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more search I found [libSoup](http://live.gnome.org/LibSoup), which looks very nice and is really easy to use. But beware: libSoup is part of GNOME - so this might not be so micro after all when it comes to dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Several of your weekends later ... I would suggest [Kore](https://kore.io/) and [Balde](https://balde.rgm.io/) (inspired on [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)).

Answer (score 2):

... ehm, I take it your weekend is about over by now, but, here it is: [Klone](http://www.koanlogic.com/)

Comment: thanks! The weekend is indeed long over, but Klone looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You want an HTTP server library. I would suggest [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).